# What to do when SaveChanges fails in Entity Framework - restoring model properties using same context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am writing a ASP.NET MVC application that uses Entity Framework 6.1.3 as the ERM to SQL Server.

My problem is that when I attempt to delete a model instance and a DbUpdateException is encountered when calling SaveChanges on the DBContext then until DBContext is disposed of then the model has null values for its virtual properties. As such I can't fully retrieve all property values when redisplaying the model in the Delete view with a message indicating that the system encountered an error.

I am using the repository design pattern, unit of work and a service layer.

Here is my DeleteConfirmed method from my Controller:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id, OfficerListViewModel listViewModel)
    {
        var model = officerService.Find(id);
        RemoveRelatedRecords(model);
        if (!officerService.Delete(model))
        {
            var viewModel = mapper.Map<Officer, OfficerViewModel>(model);
            viewModel.SetupViewModelForDetails(rBACUserService, statuteService, fishingActivityTypeService, zoneService, sanctionService, sRoleService);
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Index", listViewModel.GetRouteValues());
    }
```

Here is my Delete method from my service:

```
    public bool Delete(Officer model)
    {
        try
        {
            this.unitOfWork.OfficerRepository.Delete(model);
            this.unitOfWork.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            validationDictionary.AddModelError("error_msg", "There was a problem deleting the record");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Here is the Delete method from my Generic Repository:

```
    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }
```

Here is the save method from the UnitOfWork class:

```
    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I am using Unity and the PerRequestLifetimeManager to manage disposal of the context in my Unit of Work.

I know what referential integrity errors are causing the DbUpdateException and can check for those first before attempting to SaveChanges, I just hoped that I could avoid having to check for all possible orphan records before deleting a record.

Comment: I don't fully understand this part: _"then until DBContext is disposed of then the model has null values for its virtual properties"_. This wording suggests that as long as the context is not disposed, virtual properties are null. But once it is disposed, they become non-null, which I believe is pretty impossible. Could you clear that part up please?

Comment: If your property values are becoming null after you are calling `RemoveRelatedRecords(model);` and you need to display them in the view, then why don't you simply map the `viewmodel` before doing that i.e. declare `var viewModel = mapper.Map<Officer, OfficerViewModel>(model);` before you call `RemoveRelatedRecords(model);`

Comment: Hi Balazs. Ok clarification, once DbContext is disposed and I retrieve the item again from the service/repository then the virtual properties are restored.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just mapping the view model before attempting to delete. That way if the delete failed, then the view model is already setup to return to the view.